# Send captured TCP packets through Wireshark as PDML to remote system

Tags: tcp, network-programming, wireshark

I have 'Sender.exe' and 'Receiver.exe'. Sender will send the images to the receiver.  I have captured the packets sent by Sender to receiver through Wireshark and exported them as PDML format.

Now, I have to fuzz the captured packets and send to the receiver system.  As a first step, I need to know the following:  Is there a way to send the packets captured in PDML format or XML format?

Comment: Fuzz? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: My aim is to fuzz tha packets sent to the receiver.exe and test the receiver application on how it behaves for fuzzed packet. So I would like to know how to send the captured packet to receiver.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you would have to 1) hope that *every single byte of the packet* was represented as a field with `value=` and 2) write your own code to take all the `value=`s of the fields and put them into a binary packet (i.e., *undo* the conversion of the raw packet data into PDML) and send that packet.

There is nothing in Wireshark that will do this for you.